# ggplot2 removing NA for certain geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, na, geom-point

I am trying to create a combined plot that includes a `geom_point` of all points and a polygon surrounding groups of data using `geom_encircle`. However, I only want specific groups encircled. I have some example code below to help illustrate.

```
x <- c(10, 12, 4, 18, 6, 9, 2, 2, 7, 23, 13, 13, 11, 6, 22)
y <- c(3, 2, 12, 15, 23, 20, 6, 21, 6, 8, 15, 19, 10, 18, 14)
group <- c("a", "b", "b", "b","b","b","b", "c", "c", "c","c","c", "c", "d", "e")
class <- c(NA, "1", "1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2", NA, NA)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,group,class))
df$x <- as.numeric(df$x)
df$y <- as.numeric(df$y)



library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_encircle(aes(fill = class), s_shape = 1, expand = 0,
                alpha = 0.2, color = "black", na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE)
```

The diagram below is what I get, however, I do not want the the grey triangle, only the blue and red shapes. I thought setting `na.rm = TRUE` would remove those rows for the `geom_encircle` but it does not ( I assume the NA's need to be in the x or y columns). I have also played about a little bit trying to subset data however I have been unsuccessful in keeping the dots but removing the shape.

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `geom_*` function has a data argument, that you can use to override the data from the previous layers. Just filter the NAs in the class column and use the filtered data in the `geom_encircle` function:

```r
x <- c(10, 12, 4, 18, 6, 9, 2, 2, 7, 23, 13, 13, 11, 6, 22)
y <- c(3, 2, 12, 15, 23, 20, 6, 21, 6, 8, 15, 19, 10, 18, 14)
group <- c("a", "b", "b", "b","b","b","b", "c", "c", "c","c","c", "c", "d", "e")
class <- c(NA, "1", "1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2", NA, NA)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,group,class))
df$x <- as.numeric(df$x)
df$y <- as.numeric(df$y)



library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggalt':
#>   method                  from   
#>   grid.draw.absoluteGrob  ggplot2
#>   grobHeight.absoluteGrob ggplot2
#>   grobWidth.absoluteGrob  ggplot2
#>   grobX.absoluteGrob      ggplot2
#>   grobY.absoluteGrob      ggplot2

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_encircle(data = df[!is.na(df$class),], aes(fill = class), s_shape = 1, expand = 0,
                alpha = 0.2, color = "black", na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the rows containing NAs entirely you can simply use the `drop_na` function from tidyverse. Using the pipe operator `%>%` you can pass the data frame with NA rows removed straight into the ggplot object as such.

```
df %>%
drop_na() %>%
ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
geom_point(aes(color = group)) +
geom_encircle(aes(fill = class), s_shape = 1, expand = 0,
            alpha = 0.2, color = "black", na.rm = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE)
```